# How does @SessionAttribute works in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Why do we need `@ModelAttribute("")` while using `@SessionAttribute` in Spring MVC.

Comment: Is session a type of model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@SessionAttribute` keeps your data on session. What data is stored on session is gives from `@ModelAttribute("")` . So we need both.
For example:

```
@SessionAttributes("id")
public class LoginController {

    @ModelAttribute("id")
    public User setUpUserForm() {
        return new id();
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, the model attribute `'id'` will be added to the session if the name attribute of the `@ModelAttribute` and `@SessionAttributes` annotations is same.

`@SessionAttributes` annotation is used to store the model attribute in the session.

Answer (score 1):

`@SessionAttributes` annotation is used to store the model attribute in the session. This annotation is used at controller class level.

```
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class LoginController {

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User setUpUserForm() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet, the model attribute ‘user’ will be added to the session if the name attribute of the `@ModelAttribute` and `@SessionAttributes` annotations is same.

`@SessionAttribute` annotation is also used to retrieve the existing attribute from session that is managed globally and it is used at method parameter as shown follows.

```
@GetMapping("/info")
public String userInfo(@SessionAttribute("user") User user) {
    return "user";
}
```